# Git errors with maven release plugin

Tags: git, maven, bamboo

I try to release my project via bamboo with maven but suddenly I get these errors:

```
build   12-Jun-2015 08:27:13    [INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.3:perform (default-cli) @ roadkit ---
build   12-Jun-2015 08:27:13    [INFO] Change the default 'git' provider implementation to 'jgit'.
build   12-Jun-2015 08:27:13    [INFO] Checking out the project to perform the release ...
build   12-Jun-2015 08:27:13    [INFO] cloning [roadkit-2.0.10] to W:\bamboo\build-dir\159645699\ROADKIT-DEF-RELEASE\target\checkout
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Counting objects: 5407
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Counting objects: 5407
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:   0% (   1/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:   1% (  23/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:   2% (  46/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:   3% (  69/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:   4% (  92/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:   5% ( 114/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:   6% ( 137/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:   7% ( 160/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:   8% ( 183/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:   9% ( 206/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  10% ( 228/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  11% ( 251/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  12% ( 274/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  13% ( 297/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  14% ( 320/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  15% ( 342/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  16% ( 365/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  17% ( 388/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  18% ( 411/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  19% ( 434/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  20% ( 456/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  21% ( 479/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  22% ( 502/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  23% ( 525/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  24% ( 548/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  25% ( 570/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  26% ( 593/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  27% ( 616/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  28% ( 639/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  29% ( 662/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  30% ( 684/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  31% ( 707/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  32% ( 730/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  33% ( 753/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  34% ( 776/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  35% ( 798/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  36% ( 821/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  37% ( 844/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  38% ( 867/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  39% ( 890/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  40% ( 912/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  41% ( 935/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  42% ( 958/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  43% ( 981/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  44% (1004/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  45% (1026/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  46% (1049/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  47% (1072/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  48% (1095/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  49% (1118/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  50% (1140/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  51% (1163/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  52% (1186/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  53% (1209/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  54% (1232/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  55% (1254/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  56% (1277/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  57% (1300/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  58% (1323/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  59% (1346/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  60% (1368/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  61% (1391/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  62% (1414/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  63% (1437/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  64% (1460/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  65% (1482/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  66% (1505/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  67% (1528/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  68% (1551/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  69% (1574/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  70% (1596/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  71% (1619/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  72% (1642/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  73% (1665/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  74% (1688/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  75% (1710/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  76% (1733/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  77% (1756/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  78% (1779/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  79% (1802/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  80% (1824/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  81% (1847/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  82% (1870/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  83% (1893/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  84% (1916/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  85% (1938/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  86% (1961/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  87% (1984/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  88% (2007/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  89% (2030/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  90% (2052/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  91% (2075/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  92% (2098/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  93% (2121/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  94% (2144/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  95% (2166/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  96% (2189/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  97% (2212/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  98% (2235/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects:  99% (2258/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2280/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2280/2280)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:        0% (   1/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:        1% (  55/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:        2% ( 109/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:        3% ( 163/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:        4% ( 217/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:        5% ( 271/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:        6% ( 325/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:        7% ( 379/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:        8% ( 433/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:        9% ( 487/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       10% ( 541/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       11% ( 595/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       12% ( 649/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       13% ( 703/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       14% ( 757/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       15% ( 812/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       16% ( 866/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       17% ( 920/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       18% ( 974/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       19% (1028/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       20% (1082/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       21% (1136/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       22% (1190/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       23% (1244/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       24% (1298/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       25% (1352/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       26% (1406/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       27% (1460/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       28% (1514/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       29% (1569/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       30% (1623/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       31% (1677/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       32% (1731/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       33% (1785/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       34% (1839/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       35% (1893/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       36% (1947/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       37% (2001/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       38% (2055/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       39% (2109/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       40% (2163/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       41% (2217/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       42% (2271/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       43% (2326/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       44% (2380/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       45% (2434/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       46% (2488/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       47% (2542/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       48% (2596/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       49% (2650/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       50% (2704/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       51% (2758/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       52% (2812/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       53% (2866/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       54% (2920/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       55% (2974/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       56% (3028/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       57% (3082/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       58% (3137/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       59% (3191/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       60% (3245/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       61% (3299/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       62% (3353/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       63% (3407/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       64% (3461/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       65% (3515/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       66% (3569/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       67% (3623/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       68% (3677/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       69% (3731/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       70% (3785/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       71% (3839/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       72% (3894/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       73% (3948/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       74% (4002/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       75% (4056/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       76% (4110/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       77% (4164/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       78% (4218/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       79% (4272/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       80% (4326/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       81% (4380/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       82% (4434/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       83% (4488/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       84% (4542/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       85% (4596/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       86% (4651/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       87% (4705/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       88% (4759/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       89% (4813/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       90% (4867/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       91% (4921/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       92% (4975/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       93% (5029/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       94% (5083/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       95% (5137/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       96% (5191/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       97% (5245/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       98% (5299/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:       99% (5353/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:      100% (5407/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Receiving objects:      100% (5407/5407)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Resolving deltas:         1% (  21/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Resolving deltas:         2% (  42/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Resolving deltas:         3% (  62/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Resolving deltas:         4% (  83/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Resolving deltas:         5% ( 103/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Resolving deltas:         6% ( 124/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Resolving deltas:         7% ( 145/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Resolving deltas:         8% ( 165/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Resolving deltas:         9% ( 186/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Resolving deltas:        10% ( 206/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Resolving deltas:        11% ( 227/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Resolving deltas:        12% ( 248/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Resolving deltas:        13% ( 268/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Resolving deltas:        14% ( 289/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Resolving deltas:        15% ( 309/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Resolving deltas:        16% ( 330/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Resolving deltas:        17% ( 351/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Resolving deltas:        18% ( 371/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Resolving deltas:        19% ( 392/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Resolving deltas:        20% ( 412/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:14    Resolving deltas:        21% ( 433/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        22% ( 454/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        23% ( 474/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        24% ( 495/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        25% ( 515/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        26% ( 536/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        27% ( 557/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        28% ( 577/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        29% ( 598/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        30% ( 618/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        31% ( 639/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        32% ( 660/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        33% ( 680/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        34% ( 701/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        35% ( 721/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        36% ( 742/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        37% ( 763/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        38% ( 783/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        39% ( 804/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        40% ( 824/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        41% ( 845/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        42% ( 866/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        43% ( 886/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        44% ( 907/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        45% ( 927/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        46% ( 948/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        47% ( 969/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        48% ( 989/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        49% (1010/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        50% (1030/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        51% (1051/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        52% (1072/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        53% (1092/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        54% (1113/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        55% (1133/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        56% (1154/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        57% (1175/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        58% (1195/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        59% (1216/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        60% (1236/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        61% (1257/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        62% (1278/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        63% (1298/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        64% (1319/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        65% (1339/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        66% (1360/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        67% (1381/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        68% (1401/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        69% (1422/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        70% (1442/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        71% (1463/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        72% (1484/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        73% (1504/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        74% (1525/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        75% (1545/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        76% (1566/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        77% (1587/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        78% (1607/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        79% (1628/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        80% (1648/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        81% (1669/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        82% (1690/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        83% (1710/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        84% (1731/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        85% (1751/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        86% (1772/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        87% (1793/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        88% (1813/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        89% (1834/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        90% (1854/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        91% (1875/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        92% (1896/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        93% (1916/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        94% (1937/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        95% (1957/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        96% (1978/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        97% (1999/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        98% (2019/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:        99% (2040/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:       100% (2060/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Resolving deltas:       100% (2060/2060)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:      1% (  2/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:      2% (  3/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:      3% (  5/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:      4% (  6/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:      5% (  7/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:      6% (  9/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:      7% ( 10/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:      8% ( 12/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:      9% ( 13/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     10% ( 14/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     11% ( 16/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     12% ( 17/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     13% ( 18/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     14% ( 20/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     15% ( 21/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     16% ( 23/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     17% ( 24/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     18% ( 25/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     19% ( 27/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     20% ( 28/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     21% ( 29/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     22% ( 31/138)

error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     65% ( 90/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     66% ( 92/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     67% ( 93/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     68% ( 94/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     69% ( 96/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     70% ( 97/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     71% ( 98/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     72% (100/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     73% (101/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     74% (103/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     75% (104/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     76% (105/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     77% (107/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     78% (108/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     79% (110/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     80% (111/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     81% (112/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     82% (114/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     83% (115/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     84% (116/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     85% (118/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     86% (119/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     87% (121/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     88% (122/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     89% (123/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     90% (125/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     91% (126/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     92% (127/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     93% (129/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     94% (130/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     95% (132/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     96% (133/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     97% (134/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     98% (136/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:     99% (137/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:    100% (138/138)
error   12-Jun-2015 08:27:15    Updating references:    100% (138/138)
```

Actual failure error

```
build   12-Jun-2015 08:27:17    [INFO] checkout tag [roadkit-2.0.10] at W:\bamboo\build-dir\159645699\ROADKIT-DEF-RELEASE\target\checkout
build   12-Jun-2015 08:27:17    [ERROR] Exception while executing SCM command.
build   12-Jun-2015 08:27:17    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   12-Jun-2015 08:27:17    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
build   12-Jun-2015 08:27:17    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   12-Jun-2015 08:27:17    [INFO] Total time: 46.728s
build   12-Jun-2015 08:27:17    [INFO] Finished at: Fri Jun 12 08:27:17 CEST 2015
build   12-Jun-2015 08:27:17    [INFO] Final Memory: 15M/123M
build   12-Jun-2015 08:27:17    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
build   12-Jun-2015 08:27:17    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3:perform (default-cli) on project roadkit: An error is occurred in the checkout process: Exception while executing SCM command. JGit checkout failure! Ref roadkit-2.0.10 can not be resolved -> [Help 1]
```

Why is this? I have another project on bamboo with the exact same settings and that doesn't give any error.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: same release plugin version? that plugin had some bugs related to git so older versions may cause this.

Comment: @wemu Exactly the same version

Comment: EDIT: Added the actual failure error

Comment: Can you try with the latest release plugin (2.5.2) ?

Comment: the tag it complains about is there? You can also add -X to the mvn command so the exact git commands executed are shown. That often helps to understand what is going on.

Comment: @wemu The tag is there and -X doesn't show the Git commands